# Difference between {align} and {aligned}[t]

Tags: equations, align

When I use `{align*}`, it shifts the expressions on the right of the `=` to the far right of the equation. But when I use `{aligned}[t]` it works normally.
The following is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  x + 3y + 4z &=& 2\\
  3y - 4z &=& 5\\
  3 &=& 4
\end{align*}\\
$ \! \begin{aligned}[t]
        x + 3y + 4z &=& 2\\
        3y - 4z &=& 5\\
        3 &=& 4
     \end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've searched this question but the answers are usually about other ways of writing it without explanation.
So what is the purpose of `\!`, `[t]` and how is `aligned` different from `align`?

Comment: Single & is marking the alignment, not two around =, remove the latter one on each line

Comment: `align` is a full math display, `aligned` is just an alignment building block.

Comment: your aligned version doesn't work normally as you show in the image it is also setting the = with incorrect spacing and the right hand side is also flush right (but hard to see as you just have single digits)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're using the environments incorrectly. Here's how you could (should...) use them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  x + 3y + 4z &= 2 \\
      3y - 4z &= 5 \\
            z &= 4
\end{align*}

\[
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    x + 3y + 4z &= 2 \\
        3y - 4z &= 5
              x &= 4
  \end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

Some things to note:

- The alignment around the relation `=` is made using a single `&` on the *left*. This differs from the `eqnarray` usage of `&` other *both sides* of the relation.
- `align*` sets an unnumbered alignment that is always centred with respect to the text block.
- `aligned` sets a block with a similar interface to `align*` that can be used as inline math or within a display setting. The optional parameter allows you to specify a vertical alignment parameter with respect to the surrounding content. As an example, see

  [image]

  ```
  Before
  $\begin{aligned}[t]
    a &= b \\
    c &= d
  \end{aligned}$
  between
  $\begin{aligned}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d
  \end{aligned}$
  after
  $\begin{aligned}[b]
    a &= b \\
    c &= d
  \end{aligned}$
  end.
  ```

Comment: Is there a document mentioning the parameter of `aligned`?

Comment: @IvanaGyro: See p 9 of the [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [User Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf): "Like the `array` environment, these -`ed` variants also take an optional `[t]`, `[b]` or the default `[c]` argument to specify vertical positioning."

Comment: Thank you for providing this information.