# What's the difference between align and aligned?

Tags: amsmath

I've used both before, but I am unable to tell the difference between the two environments in the code and output. Could someone tell me the difference and when I should use them?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8788 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401201 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95402/ might be of interest. `align` is a display math environment, `aligned` doesn't start math mode, so has to be used inside other math environments, and is only the width of its content.

Comment: When should I use them? @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @Kookie - Do please read the two linked postings provided by TorbjørnT. If, after reading these postings, you continue to be unsure about when it's better to use `align` than `aligned` (or vice versa), please edit your query (or post a new query) to point out the nature of the uncertainly you're grappling with.

Comment: For instance, when you want a single number for the group of aligned equations, or when you want to have an alignment of a subgroup inside another maths environment.